# Link a C++/CLI library in a CLR console project

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I see on a question that it wasn't possible to link a static C++/CLI library, so I generated a dynamic one and try to link it in a C++ CLR console project with no success
I get:
Error   1   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) cBox::.ctor  pTest9.obj
I put the dll (Project ->reference->add new reference) set the include files in the project
(include file with no code)

I don't know what to do (I am new with the C++/CLI)

thanks for suggestions/solution

Library Project declared as DLL

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref class cBox
{
public:
cBox() ;
cBox(double lv,double bv,double hv);

double Volume();

private:
double Length;
double Width;
double Height;
};
```

CODE OF THE LIBRARY :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cBox.h"


cBox::cBox() 
{
Console::WriteLine(L"No arg constructor called");

Length  = 1.0 ;
Width       = 1.0 ;
Height  = 1.0   ;

}

cBox::cBox(double lv,double bv,double hv)
{
Console::WriteLine(L"Constructor called");

Length  =   lv;
Width       =   bv;
Height  =   hv;

}
double cBox::Volume()
{
    return Length*Width*Height;
}
```

Then in the Console CLR Project I try to link this library, I get its .h file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cBox.h"

using namespace System;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

Console::WriteLine(L"Test Library:\n");

cBox^ oBox; // handle of type box

oBox = gcnew cBox;

Console::WriteLine(L"Default Box Volume {0}",oBox->Volume());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code if we are going to be able to help you

Comment: So you want to compile some code into a managed assembly using C++. And then you want to use the .lib from that assembly?

Comment: Actually it should be possible. Could you, please, provide some more information and examples of your code and project layout.

Comment: Do you know how to use `#using` ? You can't use managed classes unless you import them.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the support;MajesticRa I put the code on the message,JN: I don't know about #using declaration could you tell me what I need to write for this case?thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes to get this to work. First, you need to make the class `public` so your application can use it:

```
public ref class cBox
{
    ...
```

And you need to remove the `#include "cBox.h"` from your console application project; the inclusion is implicit when using managed libraries.

Comment: @pasparis If you find an answer useful you should upvote it by clicking the up arrow above the number to the left of the post. You can also accept one answer if it solved your problem by clicking the tick below it. It's good etiquette to accept answers on your questions otherwise people are less likely to help you.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it seems that I need 15 reputations to be allowed to click on the up arrow, and I click on the check sign then it pass green,was it the right thing? thank you again,pascal